# How to compile several Yesod projects quickly?

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

As far as I know to make new projects `yosog` and `yosog2` I do the following

```
$ yesod init
$ cd yosog
yosog$ cabal sandbox init
yosog$ cabal install

$ yesod init
$ cd yosog2
yosog2$ cabal sandbox init
yosog2$ cabal install
```

But each `cabal install` takes forever. How am I suppose to make a bunch of Yesod projects if each takes forever to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you're really trying to do is have multiple separate projects reuse the same cabal sandbox. You can do this by specifying a shared `--sandbox` option to the `cabal sandbox` command. Note, however, that by sharing a sandbox, you're giving up on some of the protection that sandboxes are intended to provide.

Comment: Is it common practice to share a sandbox? Or maybe not even use this sandbox feature to minimize compile times of all projects?

Comment: I personally don't end up using sandboxes that often, but (1) that requires a lot of experience with cabal quirks, and (2) it means that I occasionally need to rebuild my whole package database. Sharing a sandbox makes a lot of sense when you're working on a few related packages as the same time, but less sense when you're working on a few completely separate projects.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of unusual to run multiple projects Yesod at the same time.  Each would need their own tcp port, and run a completely separate server.  Two Yesod projects would usually indicate completely different websites that have nothing to do with each other.

You can put multiple handlers and routes in one single project, so if you have related web pages/APIs you would install them with a single command.  If you have pieces that are truly modular and reusable, you could put those handlers in library packages, but the main project will still build and install under a single Yesod program.